# Can you use one Bootable USB Drive on two different OS devices?

Tags: windows, usb-drive, live-usb, macintosh

When you install a distro on a usb can you run it on two different OS's like Mac and Windows without any issues on any device.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Yes, you can use a bootable USB flash drive on many PCs regardless of their OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things can determine whether a bootable USB drive will work on a particular system, and the OS is neither of those, because you supply your own OS on your bootable USB drive.

- **the processor/hardware architecture**

Windows systems are overwhelmingly PCs with x86 processors, but there are also special versions of Windows for ARM processors. (Historically, there have been versions of Windows for DEC Alpha, MIPS, and PowerPC processors too; these are all different processor architectures, each requiring their own version of Windows executables and libraries, and different bootloaders.)

Macs manufactured before 2005 or so used to have PowerPC processors; after 2007 or so, all new Macs were using the x86 architecture; and in late 2020, Macs with ARM processors (also known as "Apple Silicon") became available and are expected to replace the x86 Macs.

- **the system firmware**

This determines whether your USB drive will be recognizable as a bootable media or not, and may limit what the bootloader for the OS can do.

On x86 PCs, there are currently two firmware types worth noting: classic BIOS and UEFI. With UEFI, Secure Boot may add further restrictions unless you can disable it.

Any x86 Macs from 2007 or later should be essentially all UEFI, but the oldest ones may have the quirk of using 32-bit UEFI instead of the 64-bit UEFI that is the norm with modern PCs and Macs.

If you install a Linux distribution on USB and make it bootable UEFI-style, it should work on most modern PCs and x86 Macs. With some older x86 Macs, you might have to add a 32-bit copy of the UEFI bootloader to cover the 32-bit UEFI firmware case.

With a bit more effort (or a clever installer software), you could make your USB dual BIOS/UEFI bootable, covering both new and old PCs, and the x86 Macs.

The new Apple Silicon (ARM) Macs seem to be using [a different boot scheme called iBoot](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/boot-process-secac71d5623/web), about which I don't know much yet. But since the ARM processor architecture requires a completely different set of binaries anyway, it might not be worth the trouble to attempt to create a hybrid iBoot/UEFI(/BIOS?) boot media.